# How to switch cameras in PWA app built with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, progressive-web-apps, samsung-mobile, web-mediarecorder

I have a code which records or uploads the videos. The app is built using create-react-app and is a PWA.
I have used facingMode constraint but it still doesnt switch cameras on mobile phone (Samung fold 2) even in motorola phone it doesnt have the same affect.
Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import config from '../../config';


const MediaRecorderCapture = props => {
  const [mediaRecorder, setMediaRecorder] = useState({});
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const [showRear, setShowRear] = useState(false);
  const recorderRef = useRef();
  const playerRef = useRef();

  /**
   * Initialize the MediaRecorder on component mount
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("reinitializing..")
    initializeMediaRecorder();
  }, [showRear])

  /**
   * Upon MedaRecorder being set, monitor the following events
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    let chunks = [];

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data)

    mediaRecorder.onstop = e => {
      let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'video/mp4' });
      chunks = [];

      let url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
      handleVideoRecorder(blob);
      // uploadVideo(blob);
      // setPlaybackPreview(url);
      // createDownloadLink(url);
    }

    mediaRecorder.onerror = e => {
      console.log('Error recording stream');
      console.log(e.error);
    }

    console.log('MediaRecorder ready');
  }, [mediaRecorder]);



  // const createDownloadLink = url => {
  //   const link = <a href={url} download="Recording.mp4">Download</a>;
  //   const linkContainer = document.getElementById('download-link');
  //   ReactDOM.render(link, linkContainer);
  // }

  /**
   * Helper function to console out change in state of the MediaRecorder
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`MediaRecorder state: ${mediaRecorder.state}`)
  }, [mediaRecorder.state])

  /**
   * Start recording the stream
   */
  const start = async () => {
    if (mediaRecorder.state === 'recording') return;
    mediaRecorder.start();
    setIsRecording(true);
  }

  /**
   * Stop recording the stream
   */
  const stop = async () => {
    if (mediaRecorder.state === 'inactive') return;
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    setIsRecording(false);
    await initializeMediaRecorder();
  }

  /**
   * Set the playback player's source to the url of the newly recorderd stream
   * @param {string} url 
   */
  const setPlaybackPreview = url => {
    if (!playerRef.current) return;
    console.log(`Playback URL: ${url}`);
    playerRef.current.src = url;
  }

  /**
   * Get a media device stream (webcam)
   */
  const getStream = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: {
            facingMode: showRear ? 'environment' : 'user'
          }
        });
        console.log('Stream fetched and rear camera? ', showRear);
        resolve(stream);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in fetching stream')
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * Set the live stream retrieved from the media device
   * to the designated player to preview
   * @param {object} stream 
   */
  const setRecordingStreamPreview = stream => {
    if (!recorderRef.current) return;
    recorderRef.current.srcObject = stream;
    console.log("recordref ", recorderRef.current.srcObject)

  }

  /**
   * Create MediaRecorder object from a given stream
   * @param {object} stream 
   */
  const createMediaRecorder = stream => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        console.log('New MediaRecorder created');
        resolve(mediaRecorder);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in creating new MediaRecorder');
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * Initialize MediaRecorder
   */
  const initializeMediaRecorder = async () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const stream = await getStream();
        console.log(stream);
        setRecordingStreamPreview(stream);
        const mediaRecorder = await createMediaRecorder(stream);
        setMediaRecorder(mediaRecorder);
        resolve(mediaRecorder);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in initializing MediaRecorder of fetching media devices stream')
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  }

  const handleFileChange = evt => {
    props.handleFileChange(evt);
  }

  const handleVideoRecorder = blob => {
    props.handleVideoRecorder(blob);
  }

  const handleRearCamera = _ => {
    setShowRear(!showRear);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <video
        className="container is-widescreen"
        ref={recorderRef}
        autoPlay
        playsInline
        muted
      />
      <div className="level is-mobile">
        <div className="level-item has-text-centered">
          <div className="player-uttons">
            <button className="button is-rounded is-danger" onClick={isRecording ? stop : start}>
              <span className="icon">
                {isRecording ?
                  <i className="fa fa-stop"></i>
                  :
                  <i className="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
                }
              </span>
            </button>
            <button className="button is-rounded is-warning ml-2" onClick={handleRearCamera}>
              <span className="icon">
                <i className="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                {/* {isRecording ?
                  <i className="fa fa-stop"></i>
                  :
                  <i className="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
                } */}
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="level is-mobile">
        <div className="level-item has-text-centered">
          <div className="file is-primary">
            <label className="file-label">
              <input onChange={handleFileChange} className="file-input" type="file" name="video" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" />
              <span className="file-cta">
                <span className="file-icon">
                  <i className="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                </span>
                <span className="file-label">
                  Upload Video
                </span>
              </span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default MediaRecorderCapture;
```

I am initializing the media once the flag is set as well.
Any idea why this is not working please?
Guys, I am really stuck with this.
Thanks

Comment: I created a minimal reproduction with your code and it is working on my pixel 2 device and a Motorola moto X genymotion emulated device, could you provide the model of the Motorola phone? perhaps I can find a way to emulate it

Comment: Check if this answers your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61191764/8656738

Answer (score 1):

edit: to make the camera list enumerate on page load, you need to ask for permissions right away:

```
window.onload  = function(){ 
        navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true,video:true}, function(stream) {
            stream.getTracks().forEach(x=>x.stop());
            getCamAndMics();
          }, err=>console.log(err));
<rest of app>
}
```

I have built an app that enumerates through the cameras available, and then lets the user choose which camera to record with:

```
function getCamAndMics(){
     // List cameras and microphones. in the menu
       
     navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
     .then(function(devices) {
         devices.forEach(function(device) {
             console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +" id = " + device.deviceId);
             var audioSelect = document.getElementById("audioPicker-select");
             var cameraSelect = document.getElementById("cameraPicker-select");
             if(device.kind=="audioinput"){
                 //add a select to the audio dropdown list
                 var option = document.createElement("option");
                 option.value = device.deviceId;
                 option.text = device.label;
                 audioSelect.appendChild(option);
             }else if(device.kind =="videoinput"){
                 //add a select to the camera dropdown list
                 var option = document.createElement("option");
                 option.value = device.deviceId;
                 option.text = device.label;
                 cameraSelect.appendChild(option);

             }
         });
     })
     .catch(function(err) {
         console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
     });


}
```

Even while the recording is underway - if the user changes the value, the camera will switch.  This is not only great on mobile (front & back cameras), but also for desktops that might have a few media devices connected.

I send the cameraId in the configuration to the getUserMedia:

```
  var videoOptions = {
            deviceId: cameraId,
            width: { min: 100, ideal: cameraW, max: 1920 },
            height: { min: 100, ideal: cameraH, max: 1080 },
            frameRate: {ideal: cameraFR}
        };
    
        cameraMediaOptions = {
            audio: false,
            video: videoOptions
        };
        cameraStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(cameraMediaOptions);
```

Code is on Github:https://github.com/dougsillars/recordavideo/blob/main/public/index.js

Demo is live at https://record.a.video.

With this setup, I can livestream or record and upload the video to share on demand. (The backend is https://api.video for VOD and live streaming)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Doug..but I am not sure why...this demo is not working on my desktop browsers i.e chrome, brave..firefox..all are in latest versions...and also not on mobile browser too.

Comment: Hit start recording... that is where the site first asks for camera/mic access.  I hope that gets it working for you. If not - please let me know. :)

Comment: Tried on latest iOS, with latest Chrome, it doesn't ask for permissions, thus no option available :/

Comment: Ok..I tried in incognito mode on my mobile chrome browser...but it doesnt flip..once you made the choice of which camera device it sticks with that.

Comment: I *think* that is a mobile thing. Once the browser picks a camera - the other one shuts down.  I tried to actually stream front *and* back (because that'd be cool), but it freezes the other camera.